# Java listFiles return null but I can still find files when I have a full path to a file in the directory

Tags: android, react-native, file

So in my react-native module I Want to find the already created files that my app has created in

```
/storage/emulated/0/Download/xx/xx
```

It work great when My app create those files in those directory and `File.listFiles("/storage/emulated/0/Download/xx/xx")` return all those files without any problem.

Now when I uninstall my app and install it again, `listFiles` cant find those old files anymore!!

But only find the files that I create a new.

Now for those of you who think this is about permission I already check it and have full access

```
status{"android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE":"granted","android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE":"granted"}
```

Here is the Java method that I have

```
   @ReactMethod(isBlockingSynchronousMethod = true)
    public String getAllAppDownloadedFiles(String folderPath) {
        File folder = new File(folderPath);
        String result = "";
        if (!folder.exists())
            return result;
        File[] files = folder.listFiles();

        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            File file = files[i];
            if (file.isFile())
                result += file.getAbsolutePath() + (files.length - 1 > i ? "," : "");

        }
        return result;
    }
```

I should point out that the problem only exist when I run the app on my mobile and not in emulator. I suspect it has to do with the version of API.

Any Idea how I could fix this?

Comment: Yes this is normal behaviour on an Android 11 device as the owner of the file is important. You can request 'all files access' or use ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE to let the user choose your ../xx/xx directory.

Comment: Yes after thinking about this, I though that its a good security measure and it may not really be a bad thing